# How to encourage employees who waste time talking about not work related activities to be more productive instead

Tags: work-environment

How do you encourage employees who waste time talking about activities unrelated to work to be more productive instead ?

**Context**

Thought was not necessary but anyway. It's a software house company with like 20 - 30 employees, we own products that are used by 9 - 5 offices, so it's really relaxed environment here. But some workers keep talking for like hours and hours in absence of managers e.g. if they go to monthly meetings.

**Please note, I don't have any problem with it personally....**

I just trying to think, how do you encourage.... as i said above. There is no anger involved in my question, keep it biased and learning based please.

Comment: .. what is your question? Right now this is very, very broad and not clear what your question is. Can you [edit] more context and clarity on what you are asking?

Comment: @enderland I edited the post, is it any acceptable now ? or I must need to add detailed context to it

Comment: Sounds like OP wants to prevent idle time due to office chatter by banning it altogether, which is a terrible idea unless it's a call centre or something. @OP: Are your employees not productive enough, and do you have evidence of that, or do you just think that they aren't because they act like human beings every once in a while?

Comment: It's helpful for more context. Right now, we don't really know what you are referring to - a bit of background. How many employees? Are they busy? are deadlines being met? What environment do you work in? Are you the manager? etc

Comment: @Lilienthal Nope, I don't want to do that..., but idle time isn't in hours ever is it ?

Comment: I upvoted the question, because I've been in workplaces where it was really hard for _me_ to be productive because everyone else around me was talking constantly. I hope someone has an answer!

Comment: Is there work that isn't getting done? Are deadlines being missed? Are they disturbing other folks? I think before looking for a solution, it might help to focus on what about the behavior is a problem, so you can encourage behavior that substitutes for the talking.

Comment: Are you the manager/supervisor, or co-worker?

Answer (score 10):

I don't think you should do anything about it.

Since you're finding that they do this when the boss is away, it could be a sign that the boss is discouraging this. Like enderland mention, social interaction is important. They're making up for lost time.

When rules are too strict, there is a tendency for a little rebellion. Maybe in the long-run, everyone is more productive after taking a little break once in awhile.

Answer (score 6):

First, not all idle chatting is bad. Forming good team dynamics is important.

Second, the important question is whether your team is performing. If the team isn't performing it's going to be difficult to really justify any changes. And are those even needed?

But presumably you still want to influence this (as a non-manager). This is going to be difficult. A lot of it depends on whether or not everyone wants to chat or not. If everyone wants to, you are probably out of luck.

Some possibilities:

- **Be the example you want to see.** Just work. Get headphones, or whatever, and don't participate.
- Involve your coworkers who are talking in work related activities. "Hey, can you help me with this?" to your chatting coworkers *might* work (depends on the relationship you have with them)
- Schedule meetings. If you can't beat em, join em. Setup meetings during this time that you'd otherwise have during "productive time" and hope for the best.
- Talk with your coworkers about their socializing. Explain how it's distracting you.

You will have to use discretion in understanding which of these will work for your team. Every combination of people is unique and you can't just say, "do this" because everyone will react differently. But hopefully something from there can help.

Answer (score 3):

If workers keep talking for hours and hours in the absence of managers, then either their work is suffering, or they don't have enough work to do. If management hasn't picked up on either one, then no amount of "encouragement" is going to help.